# How google LB communicate to Cloud Run Service, what components between them?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am really interested about how google LB communicate with Serverless NEG pod, what does it have between them?

Comment: Why do you need this information? It's Google secret sauce! Or even if it's not secret, few should know how the low level communication are performed, event at Google Side!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.